# How to integrate document scanning into a Qt application?

Tags: qt, image-scanner

What are some resources about learning how to integrate document scanning into a Qt application?

I'm somewhat familiar with TWAIN drivers to interface with a scanner, but is this technology cross-platform or specific only to Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check these project samples: https://github.com/twain/twain-samples <strike>http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/</strike> which are Qt based. The readme says:

> TWAIN Application
>
> This is a TWAIN version 2.1 of the
>   specification compliant application.
>   It offers text based interface.  It
>   shows how to implement many of the 
>   operations needed by an application.
>
> You will need to have the FreeImage
>   installed on your system for this 
>   application to work properly.
>
> FreeImage website:
>   http://freeimage.sourceforge.net
>
> [Windows] qmake is used to generate
>   the makefiles. This tool is available
>   in the freely downloadable QT
>   distribution. http://www.trolltech.com
>   or use the provided Visual Studio
>   project files.
>
> [Linux] qmake is used to generate the
>   makefiles. This tool is available in
>   the freely downloadable QT
>   distribution. http://www.trolltech.com